# How to use a variable instead of a constant in the following statement in python with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(r"C:\PROYECTOS\PruebasPDF\ArchivosPDF\326581098.pdf")

changing the path for a variable, how would the sentence be

path = "C:\PROYECTOS\PruebasPDF\ArchivosPDF\326581098.pdf"

object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(r....)

Comment: `path = r"C:\..."`. The `r` is part of the string-literal syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to use

```py
path = r"C:\PROYECTOS\PruebasPDF\ArchivosPDF\326581098.pdf"
object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(path)
```

The reason why the leading `r` is necessary are the `\` symbols: In a normal string (without leading `r`) they are interpreted in a special way (for example `"\t"` is a string with a single tabulator, while `r"\t"` is a string with a `\` and a `t`.